# DES Cryptography in C#

Tags: .net, encryption, des

I've been trying to find out the correct way to encrypt a byte[16] variable using DES algorithm. Here's the scenario:

- The data should be encrypted in 8-byte parts. the key for encryption is: `byte[] {11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11}`
- First 8 bytes is encrypted using `Instance Vector = new byte[8]` (8 bytes with 0 value).
- the encrypted result will be the IV for the next 8 bytes.  (is this CBC?)
- that last 8 byte is the result I should send.

With this information, I have implemented the `Encrypt` method as follows:

```
public static byte[] Encrypt(byte[] data)
{
    var dataChunk = new byte[8];
    var IV = new byte[8];
    var result = new byte[8];
    var key = new byte[] { 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11 };

    for (int counter = 0; counter < data.Length / 8; counter++)
    {
        // Copy the next 8-byte chunk.
        Array.Copy(data, counter * 8, dataChunk, 0, 8);
        var des = System.Security.Cryptography.DES.Create();
        des.Key = key;
        des.IV = IV;
        des.Padding = PaddingMode.None;
        ICryptoTransform cryptoTransform = des.CreateEncryptor(key, IV);

        // Encrypt the datra chunk.
        cryptoTransform.TransformBlock(dataChunk, 0, 8, result, 0);

        // Set the new IV.
        Array.Copy(result, IV, 8);
    } 
return result;
}
```

Is this the correct way of encrypting data using DES cryptography?

Comment: You may want to accept an IV as an input to this function. As its name suggests, it is the Initial Vector, after all. In addition, since you are throwing away all of the encrypted data but the last block, this is not really encryption. It is MAC (Message Authentication Code) - which is essentially a shared secret signature mechanism.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to create an *encryptor* for each block. **The *encryptor* itself implements the operation modes (*CBC*, ...) and padding.**
So you need something like this:

```
byte[] input = ...
byte[] key = ...
byte[] iv = ...

using (DES des = DES.Create())
{
    des.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
    des.Padding = PaddingMode.None;

    using (ICryptoTransform encryptor = des.CreateEncryptor(key , iv))
    {
        byte[] output = encryptor.TransformFinalBlock(input, 0, input.Length);
    }
}
```

*I'm omitting the warning of using DES here. You might also want to take a look at [CryptoStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.security.cryptography.cryptostream.aspx) afterwards for an even easier en- and decryption ...*

Answer (score 2):

I can't help you with the C#, but I can attempt to address your last question: whether this is the "correct way" to encrypt. Well, that answer depends on what you're expecting to do.

What you've implemented is a mode known as CBC-MAC; it doesn't allow the receiver to recover the message (and hence it's not really "encryption" at all); one clue to this is that the message is 16 bytes, but the "encrypted" message is only 8 bytes.  It does have the property that it is difficult for someone in the middle to modify the message and to come up with the correct 8 byte MAC value (assuming they don't have the key); hence, things like this are often used as cryptographically strong integrity checks.  Now, CBC-MAC does have problems with length extension attacks; if you don't care about length extension attacks (all your messages are 16 bytes), this might not be important to you?

Is CBC-MAC the right thing for your application?  Well, I don't know the answer to that; the key questions for you:

- What are you trying to do?  Are you trying to "encrypt" a message (so that the other side can recover it)?  Or, are you trying to prove that the message was sent by someone with the key?
- Are you trying to be compatible with someone else?  Has that someone else specified this "encryption" method?
- ortag decided to omit the warnings for DES, but I think I'll include them - DES can be broken with not totally unreasonable amounts of work; it's probably safe against your kid sister and maybe even joe average hacker, but if your adversary has access to a some computer resources, he can break this.  If this is a concern, you'll want to switch to a stronger cipher, such as AES

Comment: True, it's not really clear what _"encryption"_ is meant in the question or if there is some confusion. Oh and anyway, about the security aspect, you are right, here's a [performance graph](http://www.sciengines.com/images/stories/aes_performance_graph4.png) of a commercial _"codebreaker"_ machine .. it's even about `AES` decryption and already unbelievable fast, not to think about what this thing does with `DES` ...

Comment: @poncho: Yes, that's CBC-MAC. Thanks for clarification.